# Do I have a motherboard compatibilty issue?

Tags: firefox, compatibility

I am having issues where one application is getting a segmentation fault when quitting and other software is not running as fast as I would expect.
In order to help me determine if I have a compatibility issue between Ubuntu 18.04.3 and my motherboard, an Asus ROG strix X370-F Gaming motherboard with an amd370 chip set and Ryzen 7 1700x cpu.
Is anyone using this particular combination of distro and hardware? What is your experience.
If not, where do I begin researching or testing this issue?

My experience is:
1) The 3D animation package blender 2.80 causes a segmentation fault when quitting the application. There are some known issues with blender but after spending almost a full week with blender support my issue could not be replicated. I simply start blender, do nothing with it then after a few seconds File -> Quit.

2) Software like Firefox 68.02 is slow to start and slow to display pages that I navigate to. A speed test today reveals I have an acceptably fast connection of 850 Mbits download speed. My observation is that even after a page is downloaded it is slow to display it. Firefox was also slow in starting the speed test applet. It took several seconds to start.

Notes on performance changes:
1) blender no longer seg-faults when quitting. I updated the video card to an NVIDIA GeForce GE1050Ti.
2) Firefox 68 starts up much faster than before. Homepage is up almost immediately.

Here is some diagnostic output after updating my BIOS to the latest available.

Icarus@linux-l13c: sudo lshw -C memory

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 5204
       date: 07/29/2019
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 2c
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: CMK16GX4M2A2400C16
          vendor: Corsair
          physical id: 0
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM_A1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: CMK16GX4M2A2400C16
          vendor: Corsair
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM_A2
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: CMK16GX4M2A2400C16
          vendor: Corsair
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM_B1
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: CMK16GX4M2A2400C16
          vendor: Corsair
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: DIMM_B2
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 2e
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 768KiB
       capacity: 768KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 2f
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 4MiB
       capacity: 4MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 30
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 16MiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

Thanks
Paul

Comment: Consider checking your BIOS version, and then running a memtest. In `terminal` do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to show your current BIOS version. If it's not 5204, then go to https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-X370-F-GAMING/HelpDesk_BIOS/ and get/install that. Come back for more info on memtest. Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory` and `free -h`.

Comment: If there are still problems, go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run the free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This will take many hours to complete. Otherwise I'll write an answer and say that the BIOS fixed the problem... and then maybe you can accept my answer. Report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

*Consider checking your BIOS version. In terminal do `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` to show your current BIOS version. If it's not 5204, then go to https://asus.com/us/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-X370-F-GAMING/HelpDesk_BIOS and get/install that.*

**Update #1:**

Updated the video card to a NVIDIA GeForce 650 Ti.

It looks like upgrading the BIOS to version 5204, from 7/29/2019, solved the problem.

Comment: I seem to have resolved issues that were my biggest concerns. I made a mistake with the model of NVIDIA gpu. It wasn't in the box and didn't really look at the label :(. My GPU is a GeForce 650 Ti with 1 GB memory. So I shouldn't expect 4K video out of it and I'll need to upgrade it before working with blender. For the time being this issue is resolved. I will run the memtest overnight and examine the reports.Thanks for the help.